# Non virtual pointer in c++?

Tags: c++, polymorphism, virtual, c++20

Is it possible to have a “non virtual pointer” in c++ ( ie a pointer that calls the methods directly without dynamic dispatch). This is because I am trying to do something like this:

```
template <typename T>
class Ref {
    T* value; // I am 100% sure that value points to an actual T object.
    /* constructors and stuff */
    auto operator -> () {
        return value;
    }
};
```

But this will unnecessarily call virtual functions when I know the dynamic type of value to be T...
I know that the user could enforce the usage of non-virtual functions like so:

```
X->Base::foo();
```

But that seems like another burden for the user. How can this be done automatically?

Comment: Can you give a realistic use-case where this would be necessary? This may break assumptions made by the designer of the inheritance hierarchy and sounds a little bit like an X/Y problem. Is slicing an option? Do your member functions really need to be `virtual`?

Comment: The only solution I can think of this is fairly heavy-weight.   Provide a proxy class that contains an instance of `T`, provides the same set of member functions as `T` with all non-virtual, and implement all of those so they forward to the contain `T`.

Comment: The _pointer_ isn't virtual (there's no such thing). The _method call_ is virtual. And that's outside of your class.

Comment: https://www.fluentcpp.com/2020/05/15/runtime-polymorphism-without-virtual-functions/

Comment: @sweenish - That link is about the inverse of this problem.  It's about how to get behaviour akin to virtual functions without any virtual functions, whereas this question is about how to prevent a virtual function from being called virtually with no intervention by the caller.

Answer (score 3):

> when I know the dynamic type of value to be `T`

You may know/assume this, but at present, there is no mechanism in C++ that can make the *language* know/assume this for any given pointer/reference to an object. If it is of a polymorphic type, then calling any `virtual` function (unless the caller explicitly specifies otherwise) will use dynamic dispatch.

Answer (score 1):

Say your class `T` marks its virtual functions with `final`, the function calls should be devirtualized on all modern compilers.

See: https://quuxplusone.github.io/blog/2021/02/15/devirtualization/

Comment: That may be true, but it doesn't solve the problem, since you cannot *force* the user to do that.

Comment: There is no other way (that I know of) to avoid dynamic dispatch of a call to a `virtual` method.

Comment: Shouldn't this be "devirtualized"?